# Import of pygame fails - from pygame.base import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, pygame

I've seen a bunch of similar questions posted here but no solution.  I have recently installed Python 3.6.4 and put Pygame into my c:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib folder.
I can import other Python modules such as math OK but "import pygame" gives me from pygame.base import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
My path has PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\;C and a load of non-Python related stuff and I'm guessing that it may be missing something.
Can someone give me an easy answer, please?  And could someone please make Pygame easier to install if it causes so many people so much grief.  Many thanks!

Comment: Try to remove pygame and then install it with pip. Open the command-line (cmd.exe) and enter `py -3.6 -m pip install pygame`.

Comment: Well that was surprisingly easy to do!  Thank you.  Only problem that I ran into is that my user id on this PC doesn't have admin rights (the PC is my son's cast-off - a sign that I am getting old) so I had to sign in as him.

Comment: You can try to install it in a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) if you don't have admin rights.

Comment: Thanks again.  I had to set myself with full r/w rights to the various Python folders on my laptop.  Everything running perfectly now, thanks.  (Today's tip - if, like me, you can't read the red on black error messages from pip, copy and paste them into notepad. And if you ever become a software developer, NEVER use red on black as an error message colour scheme!!